# Modal dialog - refresh the parent page on close modal dialog or submit button

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Using Apex 5.1.3

I have everyting working, but I have a requreimet to refresh the entire page (parent page) on the close of the modal page or press submit button.

I have tried quite a few things in dynamic actions on the parent page etc, but nothing is working.

How can I get the parent page to fully refresh when the modal dialog is submitted and closed.

Your help would be most appreciated.

Regards,
Morshed

Comment: As far as I can tell, it will work if the **parent** page is one of the *reports* pages (**interactive or classic report**). Other than that, it just won't work - at least, I didn't succeed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could either place a branch after processing on your modal that redirects to the parent page, or create a dynamic action 'on dialog close' on the button/region that invokes the dialog page, which then submits/refreshes the page.

If you think 'nothing is working', put APEX in debug mode, open your browser console, and check if the dynamic actions are actually firing.